# Additional values while multiplying behind the dot in python

Tags: python

I found a behavior in python 3.8 which I do not understand.

I execute the following code:

```
three = 3 * 1.1
thirty = 30 * 1.1
three_hundred = 300 * 1.1
three_thousand = 3000 * 1.1
print(f"{three} \n"
      f"{thirty} \n"
      f"{three_hundred} \n"
      f"{three_thousand} \n")
```

Which is basically multiplying values with 1.1.
However the output is weird:

```
3.3000000000000003 
33.0 
330.0 
3300.0000000000005
```

Does somebody know why I get so many 0 after I did this calculation?
My expectation of the output would be:
3.3,
33.0,
330.0,
3300.0

Comment: It is not a python-related problem. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8612463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Python related problem. You can read this [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8612463) to understand the reason behind this behaviour.

If you want to avoid floating point errors in your projects, you should use the built-in library `decimal`:

```py
In [1]: from decimal import Decimal as D

In [2]: .1 + .2
Out[2]: 0.30000000000000004

In [3]: D('.1') + D('.2')
Out[3]: Decimal('0.3')

In [4]: float(D('.1') + D('.2'))
Out[4]: 0.3
```